# How can I connect my switch to my fibre connection?

Tags: routing, switch, bridge

#### Question

We just got our ADSL line replaced with a Fibre optic line. Part of the Fibre-install included a Fibre panel (terminator?) and a Huawei switch.

**I'm not sure how to connect our existing switch to the new Huawei switch.**

#### Details

We have a Ubiquiti 24 Port switch at work. Works great. Currently, we have an ADSL modem connected to port 1. Port 2 has a NAS device which handles our DHCP.

e.g.

[image]

Now, we have the modem removed and the new Huawei hardware switch installed with 2x IP addresses given by our ISP. What I don't understand is how to connect our existing LAN / switch to this new one.

e.g.

[image]

#### What I've currently tried.

I've connected my MBPr directly via ethernet into Port 1 on the Huawei switch.

My MBPr eth settings:

- IP: `x.y.z.250`
- Subnet: `255.255.255.248`
- Router (gateway): `x.y.z.249`
- DNS: my isp's dns

and viola! I can surf the net (and post this question).

So the fibre is working 100%.

Just not sure how to have my PRIVATE LAN (192.168.0.x) have all my internet traffic route through this device.

#### My thoughts

Originally, I was thinking i just connect Huawei-Port-1 to MySwitch-Port-1 and then have my DHCP server's gateway address as `x.y.z.249` but I'm sure that won't work because my private LAN ip's are on a different subnet to the gateway.

Any idea's friends?

Comment: At the downvoter - would appreciate some reason why. So I could improve the question.

Comment: The modem was routing and  NATing. That switch does not do NAT. Between the switches you need a device that will NAT traffic. This device will have 1 interface with an IP in x.y.z.248/30 that is connected to the Huawei switch and 1 interface with IP 192.168.0.1 and connected to the Ubiquiti switch.

Comment: I suspect you are being downvoted because a "professional sysadmin" should know this. I am not judging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing the roles of switches and routers, and this is the source of your confusion.

A [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) is a device which connects devices *in the same network* (this is greatly simplified, but let's roll with it for now). A [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing)) is a device which interconnects *different networks*. In doing this, a router can perform something called [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which (amongst other possible uses) allows it to "hide" a whole private network behind one or more public IP addresses, thus allowing all devices on the network to share a single Internet connection.

In your original configuration, your "modem" was also a router, and it performed NAT for your network; in your new configuration, you have got a new switch sitting on a (very small) public network which allows two usable IP addresses, one of which is your gateway, while the other one is effectively yours.

So, you can now connect a single device to your Huawei device and give it your public IP address, but you will need to actually place a router (or a [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)), although they often overlap) there in order to perform NAT for your private network; you will need a router with at least two Ethernet ports, one of which will be connected to the Huawei device, while the other will be connected to your switch; the router will also need to be properly configured for NAT.

Last but not least: the Huawei device is probably a router too, thus it could very likely perform this task on its own; but it has not been configured to do so: this is standard practice, to give customers more flexibility in designing their network and placing whatever device they prefer at its borders.

To sum it up, your network layout should look like this:

```
Internet --- Huawey --- Router/Firewall --- LAN Switch --- LAN
```

You should now go looking for a router/firewall; you can of course ask your ISP (or any network admin you happen to find) for suggestions; but please don't ask here, because such a question would fall under our "no requests for products or services, please" policy and would thus be immediately closed (hopefully before leading to a flame war between fans of different products).

Comment: Excellent! I was wondering as much .. and you answered my question perfectly. Thank you :)